# How to set a Ruby hash given a "key path" of arbitrary length?

Tags: ruby, hash

Given:

```
h = {foo: {bar: 1}}
```

How to set `bar` if you don't know how many keys you have?

For example: `keys = [:foo, :bar]`

```
h[keys[0]][keys[1]] = :ok
```

But what if keys can be of arbitrary length and h is of arbitrary depth?

Comment: Are you asking, given a list of keys (in an array), set the last key's value?

Comment: @Anthony - Yes. That's more succinct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using Ruby 2.3+ then you can use `dig` thusly:

```
h.dig(*keys[0..-2])[keys.last] = :ok
```

`dig` follows a path through the hash and returns what it finds. But `dig` won't copy what it finds so you get the same reference that is in `h`. `keys[0..-2]` grabs all but the last element of `keys` so `h.dig(*keys[0..-2])` gives you the `{bar: 1}` Hash from inside `h`, then you can modify it in-place with a simple assignment.

You could also say:

```
*head, tail = keys
h.dig(*head)[tail] = :ok
```

if that's clearer to you than `[0..-2]`.

If you don't have `dig` then you can do things like:

```
*head, tail = keys
head.inject(h) { |m, k| m[k] }[tail] = :ok
```

Of course, if you're not certain that the path specified by `keys` exists then you'll need to throw in a some `nil` checks and decide how you should handle `keys` that don't specify a path into `h`.

Comment: I was trying to use dig but couldn't figure out how to do the assignment.  I really like your approach

Comment: I came up with `path = keys.dup; last_key = path.pop`, but `*head, tail = keys` is better.

Comment: for those looking for a  no-brainer solution,  the solution with `dig` supposes `keys.size >= 2`.

Comment: I have objects with nested methods that don't have `dig`, so the `inject` seems to be the way here =/!  I even tried using `dig` at least for value access, but for setting I was getting different object_ids for ActionController::Parameters objects, or values being set using certain statements a weird number of times, etc., so I may turn the `inject` code into `Hash#bury`!

Comment: If you want to build a nonexistent path as you go, you could use (in the last example) ```head.inject(h) { |m, k| m[k] ||= {} }[tail] = :ok```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it recursively like this:

```
h = {foo: {bar: 1}}
keys = [:foo, :bar]

h2 = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: {
        setting: :bad
      }
    }
  }
}

keys2 = [:foo, :bar, :baz, :setting]

def set_nested_value(hash, keys, new_val)
  if keys.length == 1
    hash[keys.first] = new_val
    return
  end
  keys.each_with_index do |key, i|
    if hash[key]
      set_nested_value(hash[key], keys[i+1..-1], new_val)
    end
  end
end

set_nested_value(h, keys, :ok)
p h
=> {:foo=>{:bar=>:ok}}

set_nested_value(h2, keys2, :good)
p h2

=> {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>{:setting=>:good}}}}
```